# Is there a way to prevent a container element's background image from being resized upon window scroll in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a design that uses a parallax effect on the splash page. In order to prolong the effect I've given the necessary elements a `height` of `200vh`, which works great in Chrome and Fire/Waterfox. However, in Microsoft Edge the image is immediately resized as soon as the window is scrolled, which given the content is an issue. It should be noted that if I change the `height` of the element to `100vh`, the image is not resized upon scrolling and the issue disappears. But, as mentioned earlier, my intention is to prolong the parallax effect. Below is the relevant code.

CSS

```
#castle {
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: url('image.svg') no-repeat fixed top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Screenshots of before and after scroll, respectively.

[image]

[image]

It really perplexes me that the image is perfectly fine when the document loads, that its scale is only distorted upon scrolling.

**Does anybody know a workaround or what might be causing this issue in the first place?**

Any help would be appreciated immensely!

Comment: styling it and height: 200%; specifically for edge should do the trick

Comment: I've already tried that. It doesn't work and distorts everything. @CarolMcKay

Comment: can you share the test website link

Comment: I'd rather not share that publicly because it's not my personal domain. Is there a way I can send it to you privately? @J.Tural

Comment: In the past I have solved this for older ie browsers by placing an extra div beneath the main content div, puting the actual <img src=... /> into the html in that div and positioning the div absolute and using z-index, I would hope that edge wasn't that dodgy but maybe it is.

Comment: I guess it's worth a shot inserting the image as an actual element (`<img src=.../>`) instead of just setting the background image of a `div` element. I'm keeping my fingers crossed. @CarolMcKay

Comment: Never mind. I thought it worked. At first glance it looked like it worked, but the image loses its size and I lose the ability to manually manipulate the size of the image. @CarolMcKay

Comment: <img src="..." width="100%" height="" /> something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I already tried both `height: 200vh` and `height: 200%` (in addition to using `width: 100vw` for each instance). No dice. @CarolMcKay

Comment: Do you have it on a dev site?

Comment: Dev site? (Like that fiddle site?) @CarolMcKay